# Use FXP in Python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I've created a Python script that copies a file from an FTP ServerA to another FTP ServerB when a certain condition happens.

Right now the copy works in this way:

```
ServerA -> tmp (temporary folder in the script) -> ServerB
```

I want to upgrade the script and remove the tmp folder so I want to have a directly copy from ServerA to ServerB.

I saw that this process can be done using FXP protocol but I cannot find a good guide or documentation about using it with Python (the only thing that I found is this one: https://ftpext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Can anyone help me figuring out better how does it work? Or, of course, of there is a better way to do it. The goal is don't need a temporary staging area.

Answer (score 1):

With use of the `FTPExt` class, the code should be like:

```
source = FTPExt("source.example.com", 21, "source_user", "source_pass")
target = FTP("target.example.com", "target_user", "target_pass")

source.fxp_to("/source/path/file", target, "/target/path/file")
```

---

Though if you do not need any fancy feature, you do not need the `FTPExt`, there's `ftpcp` in ftplib that does the same as `FTPExt.fxp_to`:

```
ftpcp(source, "/source/path/file", target, "/target/path/file")
```

---

But! – Most FTP servers do not support FXP. Do you know if both your servers do? You should find out before you try to implement that. – If your servers do not support FXP, you can still do without a intermediate file, by streaming from one connection to another.

Comment: I'm using two vsftpd server created with the docker image of Fauria (https://hub.docker.com/r/fauria/vsftpd/). I will try your solution maybe tomorrow because now I'm working on another implementations way. In any case, thank you a lot for your answer!

Comment: I think that the ftp server that I'm using doesn't support FXP but I didn't spend much time on it because I choose to implement a different solution using SSH

Comment: Oh yeah sure, sorry I forget to do it :-)